# My functions refuse to exist

Tags: c, unix

Whenever I try to run my test file, I get this error:

```
/tmp/ccCazDOe.o: In function `main':
/home/cs136/cs136Assignments/a06/testing.c:8: undefined reference to `icopy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code is intended to implement a list structure in C. Functions like icons_destroy and irest_destroy are meant to be destructive functions.

The same thing happens when I try to use my ilength function.

I have tried to rewrite my functions, renaming the functions, defining them multiple times in the header, making a new test file. I just can't seem to find out what is wrong. It appears to work when I decided to make a function called ilength that just returns a number, so I think it might be a problem with the way the function works.

Any help here?

The code of my test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ilist_destructive.h"

int main(void){
ilist x = iempty();
x = icons_destroy(1, x);
x = icons_destroy(2, x);
ilist y = icopy(x);
idelete(y);
idelete(x);
}
```

My header file:

```
// Destructive Abstract data type ilist

struct ilist_ADT;
typedef struct ilist_ADT *ilist;
ilist iempty();
int iempty_huh(ilist il);
int ifirst(ilist il);
ilist icons_destroy(int in, ilist il);
ilist irest_destroy(ilist il);
ilist icopy(ilist il);
int ilength(ilist il);
void idelete(ilist il);
int ilength(ilist il);
ilist icopy(ilist il);
```

My .c file:

```
#include "ilist_destructive.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

// The ilist ADT is a pointer to this secret struct
struct ilist_ADT{
    struct ilist_ADT *rest;
    int first;    
};

ilist icons_destroy(int in, ilist il){
   if (il == NULL) {
      ilist anewlist = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
      anewlist->first = in;
      anewlist->rest = NULL;
      return (anewlist);
   } else {
      ilist previous = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
      previous->first = il->first;
      previous->rest = il->rest;
      il->first = in;
      il->rest = previous;
      return il;
   }
}

// ifirst returns the first element of il
int ifirst(ilist il){
   if(il == NULL){
      exit(1);
   }
   return il->first;
}

ilist irest(ilist il){
   if(il == NULL){
      exit(1);
   }
   return il->rest;
}

ilist irest_destroy(ilist il){
   if(il == NULL){
      exit(1);
   }else if(il->rest == NULL){
      free(il);
      return NULL;
   }else{
      ilist original = il->rest;
      il->first = original->first;
      il->rest = original->rest;
      free(original);
      return il;
   }
} 

ilist iempty(){
   return NULL;
}

// test for empty ilist
int iempty_huh(ilist il){
   return il == NULL;
}

// free memory for entire ilist
void idelete(ilist il){
   while (il != NULL) { 
      ilist next = il->rest;
      free(il);
      il = next;
   }

int ilength(ilist il){
   int counter = 0;
   while (iempty_huh(il) != 1){
      counter = counter + 1;
      il = irest(il);
   }
   return counter;
}

ilist icopy(ilist il){
   ilist copy = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
   copy->first = il->first;
   copy->rest = il->rest;
   return copy;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling both your test file and your ilist_destructive.c file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're probably only compiling `testing.c`, not `ilist_destructive.c`. You need to compile both of them, with a command like this:

```
gcc -Wall testing.c ilist_destructive.c -o testing
```

(which compiles and links them both at the same time) or else with a series of commands like this:

```
gcc -Wall testing.c -c testing.o
gcc -Wall ilist_destructive.c -c ilist_destructive.o
gcc testing.o ilist_destructive.o -o testing
```

(which compiles each of them into an object file, and then links them together afterward; this is a bit more flexible, since you can forgo either of the first two steps if none of the relevant source-files has changed).

Comment: I don't know what those functions do. They look fairly high level and I don't know how to use them. Do I put them in the beginning of my main() in testing.c?

Comment: @user1222282: Er, no, sorry. The above are commands to use `gcc` (the Gnu Compiler Cluster) to compile your program. But I take it you're not already using `gcc`, so let's back up a bit. What command *are* you using to compile your program?

Comment: I am using RunC on Ubuntu on VirtualBox to run my C programs.

Comment: @user1222282: Hmm. According to Chapter 4 of [this RunC tutorial](http://plg1.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/RunC/tutorial.html), all you should have to do is save each `.c` file -- make sure they're saved, make sure their filenames end in `.c`, make sure they show up in the file browser (as being in the same folder) -- and then hit Ctrl+R. Is that not working for you?

Comment: @user1222282: Hmm . . . the other thing that jumps out at me is that `ilist_destructive.c` has an obvious compile error (a stray `}` at the end). If this compile error gets noted in the Shell Output tab, but then RunC goes on to try to link the program anyway, then the link error will be the *last* thing in the Shell Output, and you'd have to scroll up to see the underlying cause.

Comment: That was the problem!!! Somehow I had managed to put the last few functions inside of the idelete function! Thank you for pointing that out! Now that I have that sorted out, I might be able to finish this program in time!